# The pydoc module doesn't display all documentation for codecs.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pydoc, python-3.9

I was looking into how the `pydoc` module works in Python 3.9 and noticed that if you run pydoc server and go to the `codecs.py` module documentation, there's no documentation for the `BufferedIncrementalDecoder` and `BufferedIncrementalEncoder` classes ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNsNO.png)).

I start the doc server with the following command:

```
py -m pydoc -b
```

I tried to find an online pydoc server for clarity, but only found it for [Python 2.7](http://gae-pydoc.appspot.com/codecs).
As you can see, BufferedIncrementalDecoder and BufferedIncrementalEncoder are also missing, although they are in the [codecs.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/codecs.py) module.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two classes `BufferedIncrementalDecoder` and `BufferedIncrementalEncoder` are not listed in the `__all__` sequence in `codecs.py`

as such, `pydoc` will skip those (choosing only to show the documentation for the exported names)

If those two classes are intentionally public it may be worth sending a pull request to cpython to add them to the `__all__` sequence